# Creating an HTML diff file of 2 files in C#

Tags: c#, html, diff

I need to produce an HTML file showing the diffs between two source files using C#. I have tried using BeyondCompare for this, which worked well, but the license cost is too high.

Is there any good alternative for doing this?

Comment: There's an article on Code Project about how to do this. See [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6943/A-Generic-Reusable-Diff-Algorithm-in-C-II](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6943/A-Generic-Reusable-Diff-Algorithm-in-C-II)

Comment: You can simply write a program and use System.IO functions to compare files and folders.

Comment: What have you tried? To create a diff, you would need to open both files and compare each line, if they are equal or not... It is easy, in theory...